# Nice url structure

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, webaddress

I have a website in different languages, where "James" is the hypothetical person that's logged in. It has this logic.

**Spanish**

```
www.example.com/es/Login.php
www.example.com/es/Account.php
www.example.com/es/UpdateAccount.php
www.example.com/es/Logout.php
```

I want to make it look like this

```
www.example.com/
www.example.com/James 
www.example.com/James/UpdateAccount
www.example.com/James/Logout
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Exposing the file names shouldn't affect the security in any way. If you're still worried please post how you think this may affect your site negatively and we might fix the real security issue(s)

Comment: What do you mean by "nice"? Just removing the `.php` extension?

Comment: I've now edited the question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following as your `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(\S{2})\/(\S+)$ $2.php?lang=$1
```

This will redirect you to the requested page for example:

> http://www.example.com/es/Login

becomes

> http://www.example.com/Login.php?lang=es

then load your language files based on the `$_GET['lang']`parameter.

And btw exposing the extension of your files is not harmful for your application's security.